# I want to remove all rows from my MatTableDataSource that have montoDonar ==0

Tags: angular, typescript, row, datasource, delete-row

> My component.ts body

> **I want the entire row to be deleted from which the montoDonar is equal to 0**

```js
export class DonacionListComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['idDonacion', 'usuario', 'montoDonar', 'fechaPlantacion', 'acciones'];
  dataSource : MatTableDataSource<Donacion>;
  
  constructor(private donacionService: DonacionService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllDonaciones();
  }


  getAllDonaciones(){
    this.donacionService.getAllDonaciones().subscribe((data:any)=>{
          this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(data['body']);

          //console.log(data['body'])       
        });
  }


  applyFilter(value: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
  eliminar(id: number) {
    const ok = confirm('¿Estás seguro de eliminar la donacion?');
    if (ok) {
      this.donacionService.delete(id).subscribe(() => {
        this.getAllDonaciones();
      });
    }
  }
  
}
```

I am new to angular. I need help in removing particular rows from the table and once the rows are removed the table should get refresh or it should show the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the data response before assigning it to dataSource, use the Array builtin splice method (see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for examples)
Also, you can check the API of MatTableDataSource ([Docs here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource)), and filter the data source array, smth like:

```
this.dataSource.data.filter(item => {/*filter logic here */})
```